# DLookup previous month criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have two queries, the first shows the amount balances which I will use as closing balance in my report.

The other query where I am stuck should show opening balances. I got a query like this:

```
Edate By Month      closingbal      
April               $ 30000
May                 $ 25000
June                $ 27000
```

Now I would want some query like this:

```
Edate By Month      closingbal      
April               0
May                 30000
June                25000
July                27000
```

I have a problem with the DLookup criteria part for month.

`Closingbal: Dlookup("[closing balance]","qryclosingbalaance","Edate By Month" =<"[Edate By Month]")`

Comment: I don't believe there's enough information here to provide any input. Could you post your SQL?

Comment: Ok a minute please

Comment: The Dlookup criteria part is what is giving me headache,

Comment: The Dlookup criteria part is what is giving me headache,                                               Closingbal:Dlookup("[closing balance]","qryclosingbalaance","Edate By Month" =<"[Edate By Month]")

Answer (score 2):

Fields have spaces, use `[ ]`. `<=` won't work for month name. Need month number. If you are saving the month name, need to convert to month number. If the field actually has the month number and it is a lookup just displaying month name, try:

`Closingbal: Dlookup("[closing balance]","qryclosingbalaance","[Edate By Month]=<" & [Edate By Month])`